# Decode sparse json object to php array

Tags: php, dictionary, json, sparse-array

I can create a sparse php array (or map) using the command:

```
$myarray = array(10=>'hi','test20'=>'howdy');
```

I want to serialize/deserialize this as JSON. I can serialize it using the command:

```
$json = json_encode($myarray);
```

which results in the string `{"10":"hi","test20":"howdy"}`. However, when I deserialize this and cast it to an array using the command:

```
$mynewarray = (array)json_decode($json);
```

I seem to lose any mappings with keys which were not valid php identifiers. That is, `mynewarray` has mapping `'test20'=>'howdy'`, but not `10=>'hi'` nor `'10'=>'hi'`.

Is there a way to preserve the numerical keys in a php map when converting to and back from json using the standard `json_encode` / `json_decode` functions?

(I am using PHP Version 5.2.10-2ubuntu6.4.)

Answer (score 47, accepted):

`json_decode` returns an object of type stdClass by default. You access members as properties (i.e., `$result->test20`). `10` isn't a valid name for a property, which is why you're losing it.

Instead of casting to an array, you can pass `true` as a second argument to `json_decode` to make it return an associative array itself:

```
$mynewarray = json_decode($json, true);
```

If you do that, `$mynewarray[10]` will work fine.

Comment: `true` is important, to make in PHP Array type, else `stdClass Object`

Comment: omg, thank man, it just blowed my brain. I dumped array, saw the key, but could not access to val by it.

Answer (score 2):

What version of PHP?  On 5.2 the following program/script

```
$myarray = array(10=>'hi','test20'=>'howdy');
$json = json_encode($myarray);
$mynewarray = (array) json_decode($json);
var_dump($mynewarray);
```

Outputs

```
array(2) {
  ["10"]=>
  string(2) "hi"
  ["test20"]=>
  string(5) "howdy"
}
```

Which doesn't display the behavior you're describing.

That said, if your version of PHP is miscasting the JSON, try using get_object_vars on the stdClass object that json_decode returns

```
get_object_vars(json_decode($json))
```

That might return better results.

Comment: it has "10" index which can't be accessed through `[]` operator in PHP

Comment: Ah, got it, it serialize the key as a string that happens to be a number, which you can't get at.  The get_object_vars solution should solves that, as well as the second parameter of json_decode, mentioned above.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in the conversion from object to array.

```
$a = (array)json_decode('{"10":"hi","test20":"howdy"}');
var_dump($a);

//outputs
array(2) {
  ["10"]=>
     string(2) "hi"
  ["test20"]=>
     string(5) "howdy"
}
```

See how this array have index `"10"`? But in PHP, everything that looks like a number gets converted into a number, especially in array indexes. You can't just get `a["10"]` because it converts `"10"` into a number and this array does not have such an index.

However, `foreach` works.

```
foreach ($a as $key => $value) {
   var_dump($key);
   var_dump($value);
}

//outputs
string(2) "10"
string(2) "hi"
string(6) "test20"
string(5) "howdy"
```

You can also treat result of json_decode as an object. While you won't be able to do `$a->10` or `$a->"10"`,

```
$a = json_decode('{"10":"hi","test20":"howdy"}');
$b = 10;
var_dump($a->$b);

//outputs
string(2) "hi"
```

works.

But most likely, as Chris said, you just want to pass `true` as a second argument.

```
$a = json_decode('{"10":"hi","test20":"howdy"}', true);
var_dump($a[10]);

//outputs
string(2) "hi"
```